# CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations not being called

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates, cllocationmanager

I am in the process of learning iOS 8 app development with Swift. I have followed a tutorial on [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com) that walks you through building a weather app in Swift and iOS 8.

As an improvement to the app, the author/tutor suggests using `CLLocationManager` to get the location of the device to feed into the weather API instead of the hard coded latitude and longitude values.

So having read various tutorial online, I have gone ahead and attempted to implement this suggested improvement.

I have placed the code responsible for getting the location coordinates inside the `AppDelegate.swift` file.

**AppDelegate.swift Code**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var errorOccured: Bool = false
    var foundLocation: Bool = false
    var locationStatus: NSString = "Not Started"
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var locationName: String?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        application.setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
        initializeLocationManager()
        return true
    }

    func initializeLocationManager() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("didUpdateLocations running")
        if (foundLocation == false) {
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            foundLocation = true
            var locationArray = locations as NSArray
            var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation
            var geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locationObj, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                var p = placemarks as NSArray
                var placemark: CLPlacemark? = p.lastObject as? CLPlacemark
                self.locationName = placemark?.name
            })
            self.location = locationObj.coordinate
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if ((error) != nil) {
            if (errorOccured == false) {
                errorOccured = true
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    // authorization status
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            var shouldIAllow = false

            switch status {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
                locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
                locationStatus = "Status not determined"
            default:
                locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
                shouldIAllow = true
            }
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("LabelHasbeenUpdated", object: nil)
            if (shouldIAllow == true) {
                NSLog("Location to Allowed")
                // Start location services
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            } else {
                NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
            }
    }

}
```

And then in my `ViewController.swift` file I want to obtain the location coordinates. Here is the code:

**ViewController.swift Code**

```
func getCurrentWeatherData() -> Void {
    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apiKey)/")
    var forecastURL: NSURL
    var locName = "London"

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    appDelegate.foundLocation = false

    if let loc = appDelegate.location {
        println("Got Location!") // for debug purposes
        var currentLat = loc.latitude
        var currentLng = loc.longitude
        forecastURL = NSURL(string: "\(currentLat),\(currentLng)", relativeToURL: baseURL)
        locName = appDelegate.locationName!
    } else {
        println("No Location :(") // for debug purposes
        var currentLat = "51.513445"
        var currentLng = "-0.157828"
        forecastURL = NSURL(string: "\(currentLat),\(currentLng)", relativeToURL: baseURL)
    }

    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var urlContents = NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL(location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        if (error == nil) {
            let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
            let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            let currentWeather = Current(weatherDictionary: weatherDictionary)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                () -> Void in
                self.locationNameLabel.text = "\(locName)"
                self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.temperature)"
                self.iconView.image = currentWeather.icon!
                self.currentTimeLabel.text = "At \(currentWeather.currentTime!) it is"
                self.humidityLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.humidity)"
                self.percipitationLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.percipProbability)"
                self.summaryLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.summary)"
                // Stop refresh animation
                self.refreshActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.refreshActivityIndicator.hidden = true
                self.refreshButton.hidden = false
            })
        } else {
            let networkIssueController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Unable to load data. Connectivity error!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            networkIssueController.addAction(okButton)
            let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            networkIssueController.addAction(cancelButton)
            self.presentViewController(networkIssueController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.refreshActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.refreshActivityIndicator.hidden = true
                self.refreshButton.hidden = false
            })
        }
    })

    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

The above is **not working**. My `didUpdateLocations` delegate never gets called. And in the debug console/output I always get `No Location :(` printed out, suggesting a failure in getting the location, more specifically suggesting that the location property on my `AppDelegate` is `nil`.

Things I have done to remedy this:

1. In the info.plist I have added the two keys `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
2. Ensured that I am connected via WiFi and not Ethernet

And countless other code tweaks, and still nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Swift. But a common mistake with LocationManager is to forget to retain it. Is your var retained ?

Comment: hmm not heard that one before, what do you mean by **retained**? It is just a `var` at the top of the file as you can see.

Comment: Does it ask for permission to read the location?

Comment: Yes, in the iOS Simulator it does ask to use permissions.

Comment: I tested your code, and `didUpdateLocations` is called. Where are you calling `getCurrentWeatherData()` in your view controller? in `viewDidLoad()`? Because it's possible that the location hasn't been detected yet (it's an async operation)

Comment: @Antonio yes I am calling it once in the `viewDidLoad()` method. But then I also have the [button at the top of the app](http://i62.tinypic.com/11c63w9.png), that calls the `getCurrentWeatherData()`. Am I handling the fact that it is an async operation wrong?

Comment: Ok I added a button in my test project - on load it doesn't read any location, but when tapping the button I see `Got Location!` in console

Comment: Sorry for asking trivial questions, but: have you tried on a real device? Have you set a location in the simulator? have you tried resetting the simulator?

Comment: thanks @Antonio, no I have not tried on a real device, I thought in order to do that I needed to be an Apple Developer (paying a certain fee). I want to pay the fee at a later stage once I have sufficient knowledge of app development. But as far as trying in Simulator, yep I have tried that, it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. As you point out, if you're going to call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, then you must set `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`. If you called `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, you'd need `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`. (The fact that you see the confirmation dialog means that you've done this correctly. I assume you are seeing whatever description you supplied in the confirmation alert.)
2. On your simulator, you may not see location updates like on a device. Test this on an actual device.

   When I used your code, I see `didUpdateLocations` when I called this from a device, but not from the simulator.
3. Once you solve the issue of not seeing `didUpdateLocations` being called, there is another issue:

   You are posting a notification when the authorization status changes, but not when a location is received asynchronously (i.e. later). Frankly, the latter is the more critical event from the view controller's perspective, so I would have thought that (a) you should post a notification when the location is received; and (b) the view controller should observe this notification. Right now, even if you succeed in getting `didUpdateLocations` to be called, the view controller won't be notified of such.

   Also, your `didUpdateLocations` is initiating yet another asynchronous process, the geocode of the coordinate. If your view controller needs that, too, you should post a notification inside the completion block of the geocoder.

   Frankly, you haven't even shown us the view controller code that adds an observer for whatever notifications that this `CLLocationManagerDelegate` code will invoke, but I assume you have done that.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I think point 2 might be the case. Am I right in thinking that I need to be an Apple Developer (paid the fee) in order to be able to test on my iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record: I first put the two keys (`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`) into the `test-plist` instead of the `application-plist`..Took me some time to realize.....

Comment: Thanks, I'll make sure I haven not done that when I get back home.