# Why isn't locationManager didUpdateLocation working?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

With CoreLocation.Foundation added to the BuildPhase and imported at the top of the file, I can get location information if I put the following into a view controller with a button:

```
@IBAction func locationButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

It goes on to locationManager didUpdateLocations with a CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation completionHandler that displays the location info in another function - this works.

BUT, it doesn't work when I try to transfer this same code in my data model. I set up the model with the following:

```
import CoreLocation

class Record: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Because there's no button, I've put the locationManager code into:

```
        override init()
{
    iD = NSUUID().UUIDString

    super.init()

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse, .AuthorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .NotDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // or request always if you need it
        case .Restricted, .Denied:
            print("tell users that they need to enable access in settings")
        default:
            break
        }
        print("Location services available")
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined
        {
            print("Still Not Determined")
        }
    } else { print("Location services not available") }

}
```

I get 'Location services available'. But the following code never prints anything to console, nor does it call the function toSetLocationStamped.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    print("started location man")
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler:        //pass the location co-ordinates
        {
            (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0         //process the location array (placemarks)
            {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.toSetLocationStamped(pm)
                print("got here")
            } else
            {
                println("Problem receiving data from geocoder")
            }
    })
}
```

If I put a deinit the class Record, with a simple print log, there is no output.

```
deinit
{
    print("deinit")
}
```

I'm initializing a dummyRecord: Record from a required init in MasterViewController class:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController
{
var records = [Record]()
var subjectDescription: String?

// weak var delegate: MonsterSelectionDelegate?        // property for object conforming to MSDelegate

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)      //      // coder because class is loaded from Storyboard
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    var dummyRecord1 = Record()
    dummyRecord1.details = "All was very good and strong with a little bit of lemon on the side of the hill."
    dummyRecord1.dateTimeEntered = NSDate(dateString: "2015-07-22")
    dummyRecord1.subject = "Clouds"
    dummyRecord1.locationEntered = "Drittelsgasse 1, 69493 Großsachsen, Germany."
    dummyRecord1.photos.append(UIImage(named: "zombies.jpg")!)

    records.append(dummyRecord1)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201471/cllocationmanager-didupdatelocations-not-being-called)

Comment: How do you create an instance of this object and are you holding a reference so that it doesn't get deallocated?

Comment: Try placing the code inside init method between main thread block. I had such problem once.

Comment: To Paulw11's point, you might want to implement a `deinit` method that logs when this object is deallocated, to make sure it's not getting released before the asynchronous call is done.

Comment: I've updated the question, trying me best to address the comments - esp Paulw and Rob. I don't think it is a duplicate of the other question, and if it is, could you please explain how to set NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription (for point 1); and, for point 3, I'd really like to see the value set in the model, and not called at the view controller level (isn't that MVC, or am I taking it too far).

Comment: @Abhi, sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean to place the code inside init method between main thread block. Because this is a model, not a view that will or did load (etc), I can't see where else I can run it.

Comment: If you see "Location services available", all that means is that you requested location services, not that it was was granted. E.g. it might not be authorized if it was previously denied or if you failed to set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `Info.plist`. I might suggest checking location manager's `authorizationStatus` and implementing `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` and see if you see it getting authorized. Unrelated, but it strikes me as inefficient for every record to have its own `CLLocationManager`. It doesn't seem like this should be in the model, much less at the record level.

Comment: I tried checking with authorizationStatus, but this just returned '(Enum Value)'. From the Apple doc.s, I tried locationServicesEnabled(), and printed 'true' to the console. With regard to the efficiency, a record is pretty much a stand alone entity. A user isn't likely to create more than one record per use case, and location services aren't required anywhere else. Does that make sense then?

Comment: Re `authorizationStatus`, there are only four possible values, so add `if`/`switch` statement to see which it is. Re `locationServicesEnabled`, yes you should do that, but that's a completely different question (e.g. is it a device with GPS capabilities). You must check `authorizationStatus` to see if the user has granted permission. Re location manager inside the record, it's your call, but it's architecturally the wrong place. Plus, if it's really not an array, then don't make it an array. And if it is an array, putting the location manager in there is _definitely_ the wrong place.

Comment: authorizationStatus is NotDetermined! I thought it would ask automatically. I read that I have to call requestWhenInUseAuthorization() or requestAlwaysAuthorization(), but this (see edited code above) does not request authorization, nor does it change my authorizationStatus. I don't know if it's needed, but I've a string in requestWhenInUseAuthorization() in plist.

Comment: @Rob, where am I making location manager into an array? It doesn't need to be an array - just a single location of where the record is created is all I want.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you: I thought you had an array of records and you were making the location manager a property of each record, thus ending up with multiple location managers. If I misunderstood, I apologize.

Comment: No, a record is a stand alone object with a location as one of it's properties (set at initiation, maybe checked at deinitiiation, but otherwise I may as well turn it off). I expect the user to only create one record per use case. There are the reasons why I see it as part of the model. I appreciate your comments - making me question and learn heaps on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call

```
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

you cannot immediately start updating location. That call is asynchronous.

Here is how you should properly do it:

1) Check the authorisation status:

```
switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse, .AuthorisedAlways:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .NotDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // or request always if you need it
    case .Restricted, .Denied:
        // tell users that they need to enable access in settings
    default:
        break
}
```

2) If you have previously authorised your app this should update location. However, if you didn't a popup will appear. In order to respond to the change in the authorisation status you need to add another function:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if (status == .AuthorizedAlways) || (status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I've tried what I think you mean, and updated my question - see the override init. But, unfortunately it's still not asking to allow location services, and I'm still not getting into the didUpdateLocations method. And, if I check CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined at the end of the override init, it still evaluates true. I really must be doing something retarded.

Comment: Ahh - but i do get into didChangeAuthorisationStatus, but the if statement (.AuthorizedAlways or ..WhenInUse) does not evaluate true...

Comment: @DrWhat if you do not get a popup asking to grant location access it means that you disabled location access. It is either disabled globally or for this particular app. You only get this pop up once and if user presses NO you cannot ask again - they have to manually turn it on in Location settings. Go to Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services and make sure that they are enabled both globally and for your app as well

Comment: I think you're right, because I tried your code in another project, and it works a treat. BUT, if I go into the simulator's settings, the global setting is turned on. If I click on System Services from there, however, the whole simulator freezes (can't go forward, can't go back). I can access the menus outside the 'phone', but I have to close the whole simulator to do anything on the actual phone. I'm presuming within System Services will be my app setting(?).

Comment: @DrWhat just delete your app from simulator and install again :)

Comment: No change. Still Not Determined, no pop up alert, into didChangeAuth.., but not Authorized, and still freezes if I try to get into the System Services.

Comment: @DrWhat aaaaaa, I forgot! You must add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and/or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key to your Info plist file. Otherwise it will not work :)

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but it's weird that when running the other app with location services, called app2, I can see other apps I've run recently, including the app where location services are not updating, app1. In the location services setting, I can see app2 (with purple arrowhead) and another app, but not app1 where location services are not updating. Running app1, where location services are not updating, it is the only app I can see in the simulator, and I can't see the app in the Location Services settings.

Comment: @DrWhat Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87527/discussion-between-andriy-gordiychuk-and-drwhat).

Comment: YAY!!! I had requestWhenInUseAuthorization() in plist, not NS... My head hurts, but less than it did a few minutes ago.