# Swift Not Reaching LocationManager Function

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get my location in order to check how far I am from a certain longitude and latitude.

For some reason the program never reaches the LocationManager Function where I want to grab my coordinates.

I have set up the correct properties in info.plist and the app does ask for permission.

I added a function to check for errors and got:

> didFailWithError Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.delegate = self

            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            print("location on")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        print("REACHED FUNCTION")

    }


}
```

Comment: If you implement `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)
` does it go there instead, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations not being called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201471/cllocationmanager-didupdatelocations-not-being-called)

Comment: so I got this error: didFailWithError Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: I am using a simulator in Xcode. could it be that the wifi connection is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 8.0 and later you need to ask for permission before starting to update location. You can use following code for that

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

Above code will go in `viewDidLoad`. And implement following delegate method

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break  
    case .AuthorizedAlways:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```